# [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\myCart\public\product_images\.......]

Tags: javascript, express, file-upload, middleware, mv

I ran the following code and expected the contents of image to go to location     mentioned in path variable but instead it is showing this error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\myCart\public\product_images\5e5dfcdb791fbf15a832b374\image.png'] {
 errno: -4058,
 code: 'ENOENT',
 syscall: 'open',
 path: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\myCart\\public\\product_images\\5e5dfcdb791fbf15a832b374\\image.png'
}
```

Here is my code:

```
  First Code:
  var fileUpload=require('express-fileupload');

  Middleware:
  app.use(fileUpload());

  Add_Products:
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange=" previewFile()" name="image" class="form-control">

  Post Request:
  if(!req.files){
            var imageFile=''
          }
          if(req.files){
            imageFile= req.files.image.name;
          }

            if(imageFile!=''){

            var product_image=req.files.image;

            var path='public/product_images/'+product._id+'/'+imageFile;
            product_image.mv(path,function(err){
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
              }

            })
```

Comment: what's the mv() method? Is it this --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/mv   OR you have written a separate method. Can you share the definition of mv?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is working:

> product_image.mv(path,function(err){

but anothe problem is, that you dont create the directory with the id.
Try to save the privture in the public foldert without the folder with the id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
Middleware:
app.use(fileUpload({ createParentPath: true }));
```

By default it is `false`.